# Getting the name or ID of the User Name TextBox from an ASP.Net Login Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, login-control, setfocus, loginview

In this ASP.Net Login Control can you tell me what ID or Name ASP.Net gives the User Name TextBox?

```
<asp:LoginView 
    ID="loginViewMain" 
    runat="server">

    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName 
            ID="loginName" 
            runat="server"
            FormatString="Hello, {0}!<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site." />

        <br/>
        <br/>

        (<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" />)

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </LoggedInTemplate>

    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:LoginStatus 
            ID="loginStatus" 
            runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I would like to set focus on the User Name TextBox once I know what ASP.Net names it from inside a code-behind file.

Comment: Right click, view source and you will find it there

Comment: Almost all of .net control typically have ClientID property that hold the value of the client side ID of the control.  If you want to check it from code behind or from within controller you can do loginName.ClientID

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you show a code sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, are you look for this?

```
var loginName = (LoginName)loginViewMain.FindControl("loginName");
```

Login Control

```
var usernameTextBox = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("UserName");
userNameTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: I would like to set focus on it when the page loads if possible.

Comment: It is not a textbox. Why do you want to set focus? Besides, you should not display `<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site.` because that text will carry out entire site. `Hello, {0}!` is enought.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen It sounds like you're talking about the [`Login` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login(v=vs.100).aspx), not the `LoginView` control.  If so, you need to update your question.

Comment: Yes, I will update the question and change the text as shown by Win.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can call that username textbox (located inside Login control) same way as loingView.

Comment: @Win thanks for showing how to get the value into a variable. Can you show how to get focus set on it?

Comment: I updated the answer. `userNameTextBox.Focus();` let you set focus on textbox.