# Setting the name of an ASP.Net User Name TextBox in a Login Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership, login-control, loginview

Using this ASP.Net Login Control, can we set the ID of the User Name TextBox? I would like to call it txtUserName.

```
<asp:LoginView 
    ID="loginViewMain" 
    runat="server">

    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName 
            ID="loginName" 
            runat="server"
            FormatString="Hello, {0}!<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site." />

        <br/>
        <br/>

        (<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" />)

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </LoggedInTemplate>

    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:LoginStatus 
            ID="loginStatus" 
            runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I would like to set focus on the User Name TextBox once I have a name for it from inside a code-behind file.

Comment: How is this different from your other post?  [Getting the name or ID of the User Name TextBox from an ASP.Net Login Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117980/getting-the-name-or-id-of-the-user-name-textbox-from-an-asp-net-login-control)

Comment: Also, which text box are you referring to?  The Anonymous template just shows a link to the login page and the Logged In shows infomration about the current user.

Comment: In the other post I forgot to mention that I don't actually know the name ASP.Net gives the 2 TextBoxes for User Name and Password. If I can set a name for the User Name TextBox then maybe I can use it in markup like: <form id="form1" runat="server" class="Header" defaultfocus="txtUserName">

Comment: If I need to add another template or another attribute, can you tell me which one and show sample markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you aspx, if you add a login control (where the username, password and "remember me" button show") to your anonymous template

```
<asp:LoginView 
ID="loginViewMain" 
runat="server">

<LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName 
            ID="loginName" 
            runat="server"
            FormatString="Hello, {0}!<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site." />

        <br/>
        <br/>

        (<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" />)

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </LoggedInTemplate>

    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:LoginStatus 
            ID="loginStatus" 
            runat="server" />
        <asp:Login runat="server" ID="login"></asp:Login>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

In the page load event you can set focus

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginViewMain.FindControl("login").FindControl("UserName").Focus();

    }
}
```